# Can't retrieve results from an sqlite query which uses count()

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

```
public Cursor legsWorkout(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select count(*) from " + TABLE_W + " where w1="+ "Legs" + " or w2="
            + "Legs" + " or w3=" + "Legs",null);

    return res;
}

///other part


 Cursor res = myDB.bicepsWorkout();

            while (res.moveToFirst()){

                int totalCount = res.getInt(0);

                txtTest.setText(String.valueOf(totalCount));
            }
```

Now the problem is that I can't retrieve data because `res.getString/int` requires a column name/index and technically there is no column when executing this query only the result.

So i get this error:  `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Biceps (code 1)`

Comment: Mike's answer solves this problem. 

And note: moveToFirst should be changed to moveToNext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't enclosing the string/text search arguments in single quotes, as such they are considered to be column names.

i.e. you are effectively saying ***select the number of rows from the table where the w1 column equals the Legs column or the w2 column equals the Legs column or the w3 column equals the Legs column***. However, there is no Legs column.

Instead try :-

```
Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select count(*) from " + TABLE_W + " where w1='"+ "Legs'" + " or w2="
        + "'Legs'" + " or w3=" + "'Legs'",null);
```

In which case you are effectively saying ***select the number of rows in the table where the w1 column equals the string Legs or the w2 column equals the string  Legs or the w3 column equales the string Legs***

Rather than using `while(res.moveToFirst) { ..... }` as you are not looping as there will only be a single row returned, it would be more appropriate to use `if (res.moveToFirst) { .... };`.

Comment: Oh damn, that was a godlike answer. It solved my problem thanks. And indeed it doesn't work with moveToFirst. It works well only with moveToNext.

Thank you very much once again :D

Comment: @EgzonKorenica That's good, could you please tick the question as answered.

Answer (score 2):

A Cursor exposes results from a query on a SQLiteDatabase.
You do not need the column name to get the result, you can use the index to get the query result. You can get the count using the first index in your case.

```
   totalCount = res.getInt(0); //this will return the count value
```

Comment: I tried that, it didn't seem to work for me. I get this error:


android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column:

Comment: whats the erorr

Comment: Cursor res = myDB.bicepsWorkout();

                while (res.moveToFirst()){

                    int totalCount = res.getInt(0);

                    txtTest.setText(String.valueOf(totalCount));
                }

Comment: In regular Java, indexes for result sets start at 1, but I've never done any Android development.  Are you sure you don't need:  totalCount = res.getInt(**1**); //this will return the count value

Comment: This query displays a result which is a number and there isn't a specific column where that result is displayed. So neither index or column name doesn't work, and I get this error:


 Process: com.example.asus.gymguide, PID: 6617
                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Biceps (code 1): , while compiling: select count(*) from wplan where w1=Biceps or w2=Biceps or w3=Biceps
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)

Comment: Can you add res.moveToFirst(); and then totalCount = res.getInt(0);

Comment: None of that does work I still get a "no such column error"

The whole problem is that the query involves count(), when using that, you no longer have to do with any column you've created. This is why I actually asked here

Comment: You do realise that you have shown the `legsWorkout` method but then use the `bicepsWorkout` method? Obviously if the issue is when using the latter that you would have to change that code accordingly as well. (assuming your comment was related to the answer I gave)

Comment: Well thanks for that Mike, but yes I do have the bicepsWorkout method.

Comment: I didn't say that you missed the `bicepsWorkout` method. Rather you have shown the code for the `legsWorkout` method, the new/amended code is for that method, but you then use a different, perhpas unchanged method, namely the bicepsWorkout method by using `Cursor res = myDB.bicepsWorkout();`, instead of `Cursor res = myDB.legsWorkout();`